# Using AutoFac without constructor injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I am trying to use AutoFac and all the examples show it using constructor injection which is a suggested practice.
That's ok, but I want to know how to use it where constructor injection is not possible.
For example, I want to use NLogger in my app.

Registration happens like so:

```
builder.RegisterType<NLogger>().As<ILogger>().SingleInstance();
```

How would I use NLogger without doing like this:

```
public class ProductService : IProductService
{
    private ILogger _logger;
    public ProductService(ILogger logger)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
    }
 }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: So if you don't use constructor injection, what do you want to use? You didn't give an example where constructor injection isn't possible.

Comment: @Steven take the same class and remove the constructor. How would AutoFac give me an instance of NLogger's?

Comment: Why can't you use constructor injection in your `ProductService`. There doesn't seem to be a valid reason why you shouldn't use constructor injection on that class. Can you explain why you can't use constructor injection in there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [Property Injection](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/PropertyInjection).

In your class you can have

```
public class MyClass
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
}
```

and map with

```
builder.Register(c => new MyClass { Logger = c.Resolve<ILogger>() });
```

Constructor injection is the way to go in 99% of cases though.

---

If you just want to get an instance you need to call

```
var logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
```

Where `container` is your AutoFac container - this could be pulled from a global variable - in ASP.NET MVC (if you happen to be using that) you can do this by calling

```
var logger = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ILogger>();
```

Comment: in that case ILogger has to be a property of every class. I don't want to dot that.

Comment: I think maybe you're asking the wrong question: is what you actually want just a global logger instance? If so it doesn't really have anything to do with dependency injection.

Comment: Global or not is not the question, I may want to use it only in one method. I want to know if AutoFac can give an instance without constructor or parameter.